# html button with onclick href is not working when sending email through nodemailer

Tags: html, node.js, nodemailer

This is my button used in html where I am having an onClick attribute for the button to open the link mentioned there , where the button link is not working.

I am sending this email through nodemailer using node.js

```
<div style="text-align: center; ">
        <button style="border-radius: 5px;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 10px; 
                font-size: medium;
                border: none;
                color: aliceblue;
                background-color: blue;"
                onClick="window.open('http://localhost:3000/tournaments');">
        Register
    </button>
    </div>
```

this is function which calls uses the HTML template concept to use the above html

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
          user: 'test@gmail.com',
          pass: 'test'
        }
      });

      const email = new Email({
        transport: transporter,
        send: true,
        preview: false,
        views: {
            options: {
              extension: 'ejs' 
            }
          },
      });

      email.send({
        template:path.join(__dirname,'./templates/emailCampaign'),
        message: {
          from: 'test@gmail.com',
          to: 'test@gmail.com,test@srmist.edu.in',
        },
        locals: {
            tournament_name:tournament_name,
            date:(new Date(date)).toLocaleDateString(),
            time:(new Date(date)).toLocaleTimeString(),
            fee:registration_fee,
            sections:sections,
            description:description
        },  
      }).then(() => console.log('email has been sent!'));
```

Comment: Please update your question to add more details. What is not working? Do you have a trigger on this button to send the emails? Can you add the back-end side?

Comment: yes updated please check

Comment: how are you communicating with your server? Are you using express? Can you add the rest routes?

Comment: yes , I am using `const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var Email = require('email-templates');
const path = require('path');
`

Comment: Have you solved this problem?